# Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND with docker-compose server definition

Tags: node.js, docker-compose, host

I'm building a react, Node App and I'm using docker-compose my docker compose definition looks like this:

```
version: "3"
services:
  frontend:
    stdin_open: true
    container_name: firestore_manager
    build:
      context: ./client/firestore-app
      dockerfile: DockerFile
    image: rasilvap/firestore_manager
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - ./client/firestore-app:/app
    environment:
      - BACKEND_HOST=backend
      - BACKEND_PORT=8081
    depends_on:
      - backend
  backend:
    container_name: firestore_manager_server
    build:
      context: ./server
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: rasilvap/firestore_manager_server
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    volumes:
      - ./server:/app
    environment:
      - BACKEND_HOST=backend
      - BACKEND_PORT=8081
```

I'm trying to access to the NodeJs backend endpoints using the `backend` prefix defined in the docker-compose file, but I'm getting an `Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND firestore_manager_server`, the same is happening using the container name: `firestore_manager_server`.

As you can see in the next urls:

```
firestore_manager_server:8081/firestore?collection=test&field=nombre&value=xxxx
backend:8081/firestore?collection=test&field=nombre&value=xxxx
```

I don't have any problem using localhost.

The next is the result of the docker ps command:

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Is your frontend using the urls `firestore_manager_server:8081`?

Comment: Yes it is, but it's showing ths error.

Comment: What's the result from `docker ps` ?

Comment: I edited the question with the result.

Comment: Your React App is using localhost, 0.0.0.0:3000 from your output, and it should use the the backend: localhost:8081, since the backend is exposing that port and is running in a different network

Comment: Do you know if its possible to change this behavior? I mean I would like to use the container name as a server.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your url should be

frontend:8081/firestore?collection=test&field=nombre&value=xxxx

instead of

firestore_manager_server:8081/firestore?collection=test&field=nombre&value=xxxx